# CSS Selector "combine" Elements

Tags: css, css-selectors, jsoup

I'm new to CSS and try to parse an HTML via the Jsoup Parser for Java.

Example HTML:

```
<p>However much beautiful the s6 Edge looks, I doubt [...] the <a title="Samsung Unveils the Galaxy Note 4 and curved screen Note Edge" href="http://www.example.com/">Note Edge</a>, the dual gently curved screen [...] or accidental palm taps.</p>
```

I already get the text inside the `<p>` Element as follows:

```
Elements text = doc.select("p");

        for (Element element : text) {
            System.out.println(element.ownText() + "\n");
        }
```

Output:

> However much beautiful the s6 Edge looks, I doubt [...] the , the dual
>   gently curved screen [...] or accidental palm taps.

As one can see, the text `Note Edge`insde the `<a>` Element is not showing up.

So I wanted to ask if there is any possiblity to show the entire text, including the text inside the `<a>` Element as follows:

> However much beautiful the s6 Edge looks, I doubt [...] the **Note Edge**, the
>   dual gently curved screen [...] or accidental palm taps.

I'm greatful for every suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText()), `ownText()`:

> Gets the text owned by this element only; **does not get the combined text of all children.**

You want to call `element.text()`, instead, if you want the child node's contents included.

Comment: You, sir, deserve a medal. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
for (Element element : text) {
  System.out.println(element.text() + "\n");
}
```

You should use `text()` instead of `ownText()`, as `ownText()` does **not** get the text of any child elements.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, instead of having text plain, then a `<a></a>` tag and then more plain text you can wrap the text in  and then obtain the text of each children of the `<p></p>` Element.

```html
<p id="myParagraph">
  <span>However much beautiful the s6 Edge looks, I doubt [...] the </span>
  <a title="Samsung Unveils the Galaxy Note 4 and curved screen Note Edge" href="http://www.example.com/">Note Edge</a>
  <span>, the dual
      gently curved screen [...] or accidental palm taps.</span>
</p>
```

So your function will iterate over the children nodes of the element `<p>`

```
   //I don't known jsoup so i use javascript directly
    var childrens= document.getElementByID("myParagraph").children;
        childrens.forEach(function(child) {
            console.log(child.textContent() + "\n");
        });
```

Comment: thanks, but with the text() method, the tags aren't visible any more.. so the solution of the first two guys are working for me.